# Selected item of dropdownlist if we trigger a rowcommand event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I want to know about how the selected item of dropdownlist will be selected if we trigger a rowcommand event of a grid. I am doing fine with the strings, I don't know about the dropdownlist. My code is here,

```
if (e.CommandName == "Select")
{
    GridViewRow row =(GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);                
    txtRoomCode.Text = row.Cells[1].Text.Replace("@nbsp;", "");
    txtRoomName.Text = row.Cells[2].Text.Replace("@nbsp;", "");
    // here is my dropdownlist, I want the value of row.Cells[0] to be in dropdownlist.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have already populated your DDL on page load and the `row.Cell[0]` value is in DDL. This is how you will select a particular value of DDL from `row.Cells[0]`

```
DDL.SelectedIndex=DDL.Items.IndexOf(DDL.Items.FindByText(row.Cells[0].Text));
```